# Sort a table in ascending order in R

Tags: r, sorting, dplyr, datatable, tablesorter

I have a table with 38 observations and 80 variables. I would like to sort THE WHOLE table in ascending order, based on the values of the variables (ascending order column-wise and variables with higher values first). I am struggling with "sort" and "order because they ask me to specify the name of the variables. Is there a way? Or should I write the names of the 80 variables?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `arrange`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    arrange(everything())
```